# What kind of other operations you can perform on sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In high school, I've the learned that the operations on sets are,

$A \cup B, A \cap B$ and $A - B $ 
Recently I've come to know that there are these things called addition of $2$ sets and multiplying a constant into a set.
$A+B =\{ a+b : \forall \, a \in A, \forall \, b \in B \}$

$k \cdot A = \{ ka : a \in A\}$

I'm curious, what more operations can you perform on sets? Can you add or subtract a constant in a set? Can you divide $2$ sets? Can you compare them, like $A>B$ or $A≥B$?

Can you recommend me a book on set theory where I can find all these little details about sets?

Thanks

Comment: The operations, aside from union, intersection, difference and complement, that you can perform on a set depend what are the requirements for an element being in a set. I could have the set of colors, what would it mean to add, subtract, multiply, or divide a color. What if sets had different types of "objects", say one set has functions, matrices and colors. Can you come up with some operation for these objects?

Comment: @AndrewShedlock How about set with numbers?

Comment: We can take a set under a function $f(A) = \{f(a): a\in A\}$, the set of numbers which are relatively prime with every number of the set, the root of every number. The sky is the limit.

Comment: @AndrewShedlock Thanks for the comment, but like I said, I'm just barely out of high school, I'd appreciate it if you could recommend me a book which deals with these stuffs in detail?

Comment: $A~XOR~B=\{a+b\pmod{2} :a\in A, b\in B\} $

Answer (score 4):

Sets are incredibly fundamental, and underpin so much mathematics. It's not surprising that they've picked up an enormous number of different operations that are performed on them.

In terms of generic sets, without any assumption of the types of objects they contain, the big operations come from Boolean logic. You have unions (or), intersections (and), set difference (not really a common Boolean logic operation, but can be thought of as "this and not that"), and symmetric difference (xor; exclusive or).

There's also the power set. The power set will take a set, and return the set of subsets. For example, the set $\lbrace 1, 3 \rbrace$ will have the power set
$$\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{3\},\{1,3\}\}.$$

Arguably, you could call specification an operation too. If you have a predicate $P(x)$ (a statement, depending on $x$, whose truth or falsity depends on $x$), you can form a subset of a given set $A$ by $\lbrace x \in A : P(x) \rbrace$.

There are other possibilities, but these are the common operations we can perform on unstructured sets.

The other operations, such as the addition and multiplication you mentioned, require the sets to have more structure. It's not clear, for example, if $A$ is the set of $2 \times 3$ matrices, and $B$ is the set of $2 \times 4$ matrices, what $A + B$ would be equal to. However, if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a group $G$ (or field, ring, vector space, algebra, magma, etc) such as $\mathbb{R}$, then this definition makes perfect sense.

And yes, you can multiply sets, divide sets, add a constant to sets, or indeed compute the image of a set under a function (e.g. if $f(x) = x^2$, then $f(\mathbb{R}) = [0, \infty)$). All you need is for the operation to make sense. For example, you couldn't divide by a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that contained $0$.

There are many more things you can do with sets, depending on the structure, and maybe a book could scratch the surface by listing some of the more common operations. Sets are so fundamental to mathematics, and used so ubiquitously, it's unsurprising that there are so many things you can do to various sets. Every branch and sub-branch of mathematics has its own important operations that manipulate sets. It's not possible to list all of them without basically knowing all of mathematics.

A word of warning too: sometimes the symbols used for operations can be used for other operations too. For example, a function is formally defined in terms of its graph: a set of ordered pairs. If you were to add the functions $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x^3$, which is to say
\begin{align*}
f &= \{ (x, x^2) : x \in \mathbb{R}\} \\
g &= \{ (x, x^3) : x \in \mathbb{R}\},
\end{align*}
then the resulting function $f + g$ is usually interpreted to be the function that is the pointwise sum of $f$ and $g$, in particular $(f + g)(x) = x^2 + x^3$, which is to say
$$f + g = \{(x, x^2 + x^3) : x \in \mathbb{R} \}.$$
Note that this is different from the $+$ you mentioned! Using the sum you were talking about, we would have
$$f + g = \{(x + y, x^2 + y^3) : x, y \in \mathbb{R} \},$$
which is not a function! So, just be aware of context.

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorites is the Cartesian product. Given $A,B\subseteq\Bbb R$, we define the Cartesian product $A\times B$ as follows: $$A\times B=\{(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2:a\in A, b\in B\}$$
Cartesian products are cool, because they let you create grids/planes (and their higher-dimensional equivalents) out of sets.